# How to define keybinding to toggle between minor modes in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

**EDIT**: From the comments, I came to know that org-mode is not a minor mode. So this question is not relevant to org-mode. But it will be useful if someone wants to toggle b/w minor modes in emacs.

I have to switch to org-mode often while operating on a buffer, and am too lazy to type 
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-mode` all the time.

Is there a way I can specify a keybinding in my init.el file to toggle the mode for the buffer? I want to use something like <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: Out of curiosity, what *other* major modes do you need to use with your org file?

Comment: Also, as has been pointed out, org-mode is not a minor mode. You need to edit your question so that the title and the body text agree with each other.

Comment: @phils Other modes that I frequent switch on manually are linum-mode, font-lock(for syntax highlight) etc.

I found out that my knowledge about major/minor modes was partial. I will read the manual again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something similar to this

```
(defvar previous-major-mode nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'previous-major-mode)
(put 'previous-major-mode 'permanent-local t)

(defun toggle-org-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (cond
   (previous-major-mode
    (call-interactively previous-major-mode)
    (setq previous-major-mode nil))
   (t
    (setq previous-major-mode major-mode)
    (call-interactively 'org-mode))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") #'toggle-org-mode)
```

But if you need this frequently, it's a good indication that you are doing something wrong, and probably misunderstood the concepts of major modes.

Answer (score 0):

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'org-mode)` should do the trick.

Comment: this does not toggle the org-mode once its set. Once it enables org-mode, I cannot turn it back off.

Comment: Hmm. The convention is for invoking a minor mode function to toggle: that doesn't seem to be the case for `org-mode`, though. I'll have a look.

Comment: Well, it seems `org-mode` is not a minor mode. As such you won't be able to toggle it.